# Where to get the PyPI packages ranking order by download times?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distribute, pypi

I didn't find it in the official site.

And I googled and got this:

http://pypi-ranking.info/alltime

But I don't know the accuracy of the list here and it doesn't say this is order by direct download or download because of dependency.

Is there somewhere else I can get the ranking?

Comment: I would definitely say this are all downloads, regardless whether direct or dependency.